# Loading jQuery-File-Uploader asynchroniously

Tags: jquery, jquery-file-upload

I'm using the jquery/bootstrap file uploader from github and want to load it asyncroniously. I know I'm not doing something, but I don't know what to do to get it to work after being loaded dynamically.

I altered the demo script to show you exactly what i mean (sorry for making it so long):

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_REQUEST['ajax'])) {
        echo ('
            <!-- The file upload form used as target for the file upload widget -->
        <form id="fileupload" action="server/php/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <!-- Redirect browsers with JavaScript disabled to the origin page -->
            <noscript><input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/"></noscript>
            <!-- The fileupload-buttonbar contains buttons to add/delete files and start/cancel the upload -->
            <div class="row fileupload-buttonbar">
                <div class="span7">
                    <!-- The fileinput-button span is used to style the file input field as button -->
                    <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
                        <i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i>
                        <span>Add files...</span>
                        <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
                    </span>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary start">
                        <i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i>
                        <span>Start upload</span>
                    </button>
                    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning cancel">
                        <i class="icon-ban-circle icon-white"></i>
                        <span>Cancel upload</span>
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete">
                        <i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i>
                        <span>Delete</span>
                    </button>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="toggle">
                </div>
                <!-- The global progress information -->
                <div class="span5 fileupload-progress fade">
                    <!-- The global progress bar -->
                    <div class="progress progress-success progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
                        <div class="bar" style="width:0%;"></div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- The extended global progress information -->
                    <div class="progress-extended">&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- The loading indicator is shown during file processing -->
            <div class="fileupload-loading"></div>
            <br>
            <!-- The table listing the files available for upload/download -->
            <table role="presentation" class="table table-striped"><tbody class="files" data-toggle="modal-gallery" data-target="#modal-gallery"></tbody></table>
        </form>

    <!-- modal-gallery is the modal dialog used for the image gallery -->
    <div id="modal-gallery" class="modal modal-gallery hide fade" data-filter=":odd" tabindex="-1">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
            <h3 class="modal-title"></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body"><div class="modal-image"></div></div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <a class="btn modal-download" target="_blank">
                <i class="icon-download"></i>
                <span>Download</span>
            </a>
            <a class="btn btn-success modal-play modal-slideshow" data-slideshow="5000">
                <i class="icon-play icon-white"></i>
                <span>Slideshow</span>
            </a>
            <a class="btn btn-info modal-prev">
                <i class="icon-arrow-left icon-white"></i>
                <span>Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="btn btn-primary modal-next">
                <span>Next</span>
                <i class="icon-arrow-right icon-white"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>

        ');
        die;
    }
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <!--
    /*
     * jQuery File Upload Plugin Demo 7.4
     * https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload
     *
     * Copyright 2010, Sebastian Tschan
     * https://blueimp.net
     *
     * Licensed under the MIT license:
     * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/MIT
     */
    -->
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <!-- Force latest IE rendering engine or ChromeFrame if installed -->
    <!--[if IE]><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"><![endif]-->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery File Upload Demo</title>
    <meta name="description" content="File Upload widget with multiple file selection, drag&amp;drop support, progress bar and preview images for jQuery. Supports cross-domain, chunked and resumable file uploads. Works with any server-side platform (Google App Engine, PHP, Python, Ruby on Rails, Java, etc.) that supports standard HTML form file uploads.">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS Toolkit styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://blueimp.github.com/cdn/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Generic page styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap styles for responsive website layout, supporting different screen sizes -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://blueimp.github.com/cdn/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS fixes for IE6 -->
    <!--[if lt IE 7]><link rel="stylesheet" href="http://blueimp.github.com/cdn/css/bootstrap-ie6.min.css"><![endif]-->
    <!-- Bootstrap Image Gallery styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://blueimp.github.com/Bootstrap-Image-Gallery/css/bootstrap-image-gallery.min.css">
    <!-- CSS to style the file input field as button and adjust the Bootstrap progress bars -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.fileupload-ui.css">
    <!-- CSS adjustments for browsers with JavaScript disabled -->
    <noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.fileupload-ui-noscript.css"></noscript>
    <!-- Shim to make HTML5 elements usable in older Internet Explorer versions -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="async"></div>
    <!-- The template to display files available for upload -->
    <script id="template-upload" type="text/x-tmpl">
    {% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
        <tr class="template-upload fade">
            <td class="preview"><span class="fade"></span></td>
            <td class="name"><span>{%=file.name%}</span></td>
            <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
            {% if (file.error) { %}
                <td class="error" colspan="2"><span class="label label-important">Error</span> {%=file.error%}</td>
            {% } else if (o.files.valid && !i) { %}
                <td>
                    <div class="progress progress-success progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="0"><div class="bar" style="width:0%;"></div></div>
                </td>
                <td>{% if (!o.options.autoUpload) { %}
                    <button class="btn btn-primary start">
                        <i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i>
                        <span>Start</span>
                    </button>
                {% } %}</td>
            {% } else { %}
                <td colspan="2"></td>
            {% } %}
            <td>{% if (!i) { %}
                <button class="btn btn-warning cancel">
                    <i class="icon-ban-circle icon-white"></i>
                    <span>Cancel</span>
                </button>
            {% } %}</td>
        </tr>
    {% } %}
    </script>
    <!-- The template to display files available for download -->
    <script id="template-download" type="text/x-tmpl">
    {% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
        <tr class="template-download fade">
            {% if (file.error) { %}
                <td></td>
                <td class="name"><span>{%=file.name%}</span></td>
                <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
                <td class="error" colspan="2"><span class="label label-important">Error</span> {%=file.error%}</td>
            {% } else { %}
                <td class="preview">{% if (file.thumbnail_url) { %}
                    <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" data-gallery="gallery" download="{%=file.name%}"><img src="{%=file.thumbnail_url%}"></a>
                {% } %}</td>
                <td class="name">
                    <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" data-gallery="{%=file.thumbnail_url&&'gallery'%}" download="{%=file.name%}">{%=file.name%}</a>
                </td>
                <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
                <td colspan="2"></td>
            {% } %}
            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-danger delete" data-type="{%=file.delete_type%}" data-url="{%=file.delete_url%}"{% if (file.delete_with_credentials) { %} data-xhr-fields='{"withCredentials":true}'{% } %}>
                    <i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i>
                    <span>Delete</span>
                </button>
                <input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="1" class="toggle">
            </td>
        </tr>
    {% } %}
    </script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- The jQuery UI widget factory, can be omitted if jQuery UI is already included -->
    <script src="js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <!-- The Templates plugin is included to render the upload/download listings -->
    <script src="http://blueimp.github.com/JavaScript-Templates/tmpl.min.js"></script>
    <!-- The Load Image plugin is included for the preview images and image resizing functionality -->
    <script src="http://blueimp.github.com/JavaScript-Load-Image/load-image.min.js"></script>
    <!-- The Canvas to Blob plugin is included for image resizing functionality -->
    <script src="http://blueimp.github.com/JavaScript-Canvas-to-Blob/canvas-to-blob.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap JS and Bootstrap Image Gallery are not required, but included for the demo -->
    <script src="http://blueimp.github.com/cdn/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://blueimp.github.com/Bootstrap-Image-Gallery/js/bootstrap-image-gallery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- The Iframe Transport is required for browsers without support for XHR file uploads -->
    <script src="js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
    <!-- The basic File Upload plugin -->
    <script src="js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
    <!-- The File Upload file processing plugin -->
    <script src="js/jquery.fileupload-fp.js"></script>
    <!-- The File Upload user interface plugin -->
    <script src="js/jquery.fileupload-ui.js"></script>
    <!-- The main application script -->
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <!-- The XDomainRequest Transport is included for cross-domain file deletion for IE8+ -->
    <!--[if gte IE 8]><script src="js/cors/jquery.xdr-transport.js"></script><![endif]-->

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.ajax({
          type: "post",
          url: '?ajax=1',
            timeout:1000,
            success: function(data) {
                $('#async').html(data);
            }
        });
    </script>

    </body> 
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Start:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload();
```